# What is the best way to get propagation VHF map for FM repeater?

Tags: propagation, vhf

Is there a way to get a professional propagation map for my VHF 50 watt repeater?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about *"propagation"* but you can check an estimate of *"coverage"*

Without promoting anything, and with the normal *"Your Milage May Vary"* and *"There might be others"* disclaimers, the site I use for checking coverage is:

[Radio Mobile online](http://www.cplus.org/rmw/rmonline.html)

You need to do the following:

- setup a user account (free)
- setup a base/home location
- then setup a "coverage"

The free edition of this website will only allow frequency inputs in the HAM/Amateur radio bands.

Comment: Another option might be SPLAT! (http://www.qsl.net/kd2bd/splat.html) which has several online interfaces including one at http://splat.adis.ca/

Comment: @user3486184 never heard of SPLAT!... I will try that out for sure! thanks!